# How do paginated and filtered responses work in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm building a side project and I'm currently developing the frontend using React. I have a question regarding paginated API responses and Redux (this is my first time using Redux).

Let's say that I have an `/invoices` API endpoint which provides a paginated list of invoices. I  can also append query params to the endpoint such as `?is_paid=false` to filter those invoices. Should I have a store for invoices and another store for filtered invoices?

My idea was that for non filtered invoices, I would just get the first page and add it to the store, than if the user wants the 2nd page, I'll append those to the store as well etc. So if a user wants to go back, no requests would be made. However, I'm unsure if I should do the same for filtered invoices as well because there are several filters that can be made.

Comment: What happens if the user goes back, but the underlying data has since changed?

Comment: I guess the user would need to refresh the page in order for him to get updated data... Not sure what's the right way to solve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your terminology is a little bit off.  You definitely only want to have one store instance.  But you can have lots of different properties in your store.

Your store should contain a property which is a dictionary of all loaded invoices keyed by a unique invoice id.  You only need to have one record per invoice even though that invoice might appear in many different filtered lists. These are your "entities".

You also need to know which invoices are in each list, so you should have another property in your store with that data.  These are your "collections".  You just need to store the ids of the invoices here.  You'll get the complete invoice from the entities property.

Usually the key that I use for the collections is the path of the URL.  So your store structure would look something like:

```
{
  invoices: {
    entities: {
       1: {/* complete invoice record */},
       2: {/* complete invoice record */},
       ...
    },
    collections: {
      "/": [99, 98, 97,...],
      "/page/2/": [89, 88, 87,...],
      "/?is_paid=false": [99, 92, 87, ...],
      "/?is_paid=false&someFilter=x": [92, 35, 21, ...],
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I was thinking something like this as well but I didn't think that having a lot of properties i.e. `collections` was the way to go in Redux. One more thing though, should I make new actions and reducers for `collections` or should they be in the same one as invoices?

Comment: Use the same actions, update in both places.

Comment: Hey, I've ran into a problem. How should I update the Redux state when I create a new invoice for example i.e. how can I update the collections and the urls?

Comment: That’s actually a very tough problem.  Worst case scenario you could clear all collections from the state when adding an invoice.  That’s easy to implement.  If you know what collections the new invoice would belong to then you can clear just those collections.  But when you are dealing with multiple filters and pagination there could be infinitely many matches. You’d probably need to store some sort of meta for each collection page such that when you add a new invoice (or delete one) you can run through the array of collection urls and clear any that match.  Read up on “invalidation”.